# Function to return if is first or second half of the month

Tags: sql-server, function, date

I'm learning SQL, using SQL Server and I'm stuck in a issue... is there a way to create a function that return if is first or second half of the month, given a specific date.
For example,

if date is 01/07/2018 then 0 cause is first half of the month

if date is 30/07/2018 then 1 cause is second half of the month

I don't have a query about it, I'm REALLY begining to learn haha, sry! =D

Hope I was clear enough ^^'

Comment: A built-in function for that? Not in any DMBS I've ever heard of.

Comment: If you write and post the query to determine first/second half of month, I'm certain someone can show you how to wrap that in a function.  Are you working with Oracle, SQL Server, Arcturian Rancid-Raptor, or some other data database?  It helps us help you when you share that info.

Comment: SQL Server has a DATEPART function that returns a part of the date, such as month. That should help you along.

Comment: You can use the `DATEPART()` function to get the day of the month.  I'm not sure of a clean way to get the last day of each month, but you could get the `DATEPART()` day of the first day of the next month and then subtract a day using `DATEADD()`.  So get the `DATEPART()` month of the date that is passed to you, then add a month, subtract a day, get the day number, divide by 2, then compare that date to your original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below in your function

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(d,@Date) <=15 THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END
```

**Edit**
Your function will look like

```
Create function MyFunc (@myDate datetime)
Returns smallint
as
BEGIN
DECLARE @MidWeek int
IF (DATEPART(m,@myDate)=2)
  SET @MidWeek = 14 -- Special case for Feb (28 or 29 days)
ELSE
  SET @MidWeek = 15 -- Non feb months (30 or 31 days)

IF (DATEPART(d,@myDate) <= @MidWeek )
BEGIN
  RETURN (0)
END

RETURN (1)

END
```

Comment: Simplest way for sure, but [**i would check out this blog**](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) regarding shorthand with date/time operations. You also need a bit more logic for February but this is on the right track.

Comment: @scsimon agree, we need to handle Feb case, edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a tally talbe and `NTILE`

```
--this is your input
declare @myDate datetime = '20180413'


--we get the first and last day of that month
declare @startdate datetime = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @myDate), 0)
declare @enddate datetime = Dateadd(day,-1,DATEADD(month,1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @myDate), 0)))

--get a tally table of numbers to build our cte of dates for the entire month
;WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
    ),

--create the list of dates
dateRange as(
select theDate = @startdate
union
select dateadd(day,N,@startdate)
from cteTally
where dateadd(day,N,@startdate) <= @enddate)


--use NTILE to separate these into 2 groups
select 
    theDate
    ,half_of_month = ntile(2) over (order by theDate)
into #myDates
from dateRange
order by theDate
--this is just to show how ntile works
select * from #myDates


--return the one for your input
select 
    @myDate
    ,half_of_month = case when half_of_month = 1 then 'First' else 'Second' end
from #myDates
where theDate = @myDate

drop table #myDates
```

[Docs on the NTILE function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

This is super ugly, But it will get you what you're looking for and it doesn't require a lookup table.  It will handle months with variable amounts of days as well.

```
DECLARE @InputDate datetime; SET @InputDate = GETDATE();

SELECT CASE WHEN @InputDate > DATEADD(DAY, DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1,DATEADD(DAY, ((DATEPART(DAY, @InputDate))*-1)+1, CAST(@InputDate as date))))) / 2, DATEADD(DAY, ((DATEPART(DAY, @InputDate))*-1)+1, CAST(@InputDate as date))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [MoreThanHalf]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the 15th as mid-month

**Example**

```
Select sign(DatePart(DAY,'2018-07-04')/15)
      ,sign(DatePart(DAY,'2018-07-16')/15)
```

Comment: what about FEB though? And leap year? I like this though.

Comment: @scsimon We could have fun and interpolate between BOM and EOM and get the exact value  :)

Comment: I could dig it Jon, I went with NTILE... stole that from my memory bank of Gordon too lol

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a table, here is a function that will compare the current day of the month vs the last day of the month. If greater than .5 then it will be 2nd half of month.

Examples are:

1. Jan 15  (15/31) is < .5 therefore 1st half
2. Feb 15 (15/28) is >.5 therefore 2nd half
3. Apr 15 (15/30) is = .5 therefore 1st half

   ```
   create function PortionOfMonth(@d date)
   returns int
   as
   begin
   declare @returnValue int

   if cast(day(@d) as decimal(4,2))  --Convert to decimal for division of ints
       /cast( day(dateadd(d,-1, --last day of current month
                       (dateadd(month,1, --1st day of next month
                               cast(cast(month(@d) as varchar(2)) +'/1/' + cast(year(@d) as varchar(4)) as date))))) --1st day of current month
                                as decimal(4,2)) --Convert to decimal for division of ints
                                > .5 
   begin 
       set @returnValue = 1 -- 2nd half
   end
   else 
   begin 
       set @returnValue = 0 --1st half
   end

   return @returnValue
   end
   ```